# Raid 10 - Very slow

Tags: linux, centos, raid, software-raid, raid10

I have Software Raid 10 setup, it has been working great a few months.

When I did a quick HD speed test:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=test bs=64k count=16k conv=fdatasync
```

It is taking forever and I had to terminate it, the result was:

> 1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB) copied, 151.27 s, 7.1 MB/s

What causing this?

```
[root@host ~]# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1] [raid10]
md2 : active raid1 sdc1[4] sdd1[3] sdb1[1] sda1[0]
      204788 blocks super 1.0 [4/4] [UUUU]

md127 : active raid10 sdc4[4] sdb4[1] sdd4[3] sda4[0]
      1915357184 blocks super 1.2 256K chunks 2 near-copies [4/4] [UUUU]

md1 : active raid1 sdc3[4] sdb3[1] sdd3[3] sda3[0]
      8387576 blocks super 1.1 [4/4] [UUUU]

md0 : active raid1 sdc2[4] sda2[0] sdb2[1] sdd2[3]
      10484668 blocks super 1.1 [4/4] [UUUU]
      bitmap: 1/1 pages [4KB], 65536KB chunk
```

Uptime:

```
[root@host ~]# uptime
 18:50:28 up 105 days, 11:34,  1 user,  load average: 0.04, 0.05, 0.00
```

Memory

```
[root@host ~]# free -m
              total       used       free     shared    buffers   cached 
 Mem:         15893      15767        125          0        461    14166
 -/+ buffers/cache:       1139      14753 
 Swap:         8190          9       8181
```

**Server Spec:**

Xeon E3-1230

16GB DDR-3 ECC

4 x 1TB 7200 RPM SATA (software RAID)

I have notice when I do `fdisk -l` command - get bunch of invalid partition, is that anything to do with it? If so how to fix?

```
[root@host ~]# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000d1a79

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1          26      204800   fd  Linux raid autodetect
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda2              26        1332    10485760   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda3            1332        2376     8388608   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda4            2376      121601   957679840+  fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/sdb: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000303b7

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *           1          26      204800   fd  Linux raid autodetect
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sdb2              26        1332    10485760   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb3            1332        2376     8388608   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb4            2376      121601   957679840+  fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/sdc: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1   *           1          26      204800   fd  Linux raid autodetect
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sdc2              26        1332    10485760   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdc3            1332        2376     8388608   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdc4            2376      121601   957679840+  fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/sdd: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0006436c

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdd1   *           1          26      204800   fd  Linux raid autodetect
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sdd2              26        1332    10485760   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdd3            1332        2376     8388608   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdd4            2376      121601   957679840+  fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/md0: 10.7 GB, 10736300032 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 2621167 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 8 * 512 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/md0 doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/md1: 8588 MB, 8588877824 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 2096894 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 8 * 512 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/md1 doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/md127: 1961.3 GB, 1961325756416 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 478839296 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 8 * 512 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 262144 bytes / 524288 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/md127 doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/md2: 209 MB, 209702912 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 51197 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 8 * 512 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/md2 doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

Comment: To get a sane answer, you're going to need to provide a lot more information about your hardware.

Comment: @EEAA I have updated more information.

Comment: Can you add the exact model of your hard disks and the output of `fdisk -lu /dev/sda` (and possibly `sdb` and `sdc` too)? If your hard disks are of the "Advanced Format" variety, you should take care that partitions be 4k-aligned. Read more about this [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Advanced_Format).

Answer (score 1):

I can think of several potential reasons for such a result:

1. Way too many `fdatasync()` operations: in this case the throughput is limited by the number of transactions that a hard drive can perform within a specific timeframe. For traditional rotating media with a single head per surface the absolute maximum is determined by the speed for rotation. E.g. for data blocks of 64K, you would only get

   ```
   7200rpm * 64K/rotation = 7,680 K/sec
   ```

   I suspect that due to the semantics of RAID 1+0, each write would only hit a single mirror each time, since the `dd` block size is smaller than the array chunk size. This would limit the performance of the array to that of one single mirror, which for writes is that of a single drive.

   On my system `dd` with these options only performs one single `fdatasync()` call before quiting - perhaps yours does one per block? Running `dd` under `strace` would tell you whether this is the case.
2. A filesystem mounted with the `sync` data option would also exhibit similar behavior.
3. A hardware issue - I have frequently seen such delays due to faulty cables and failing hard drives. I would suggest perusing your system logs and running `smartctl` on all your drives. A read test would also be useful, since it should also be affected by a hardware problem - how does your array fare with reads?